# AngularJS - How to make a cascading select and save to API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I have the following JSON file that lists Countries and their states :**

```
[
    {
        "value": "Australia",
        "text": "Australia",
        "states": [
            {
                "value": "Australian Capital Territory",
                "text": "Australian Capital Territory"
            },
            {
                "value": "New South Wales",
                "text": "New South Wales"
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

**I load the data in a variable called countriesAndStates and then I display this on the frontend :**

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-control" id="country" data-ng-model="project.country" data-ng-options="country.value as country.text for country in countriesAndStates">
                        <option disabled value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 control-label">State</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-control" id="state" data-ng-model="project.state" data-ng-options="state.value as state.text for state in countriesAndStates.states" data-ng-disabled="!countriesAndStates.states">
                        <option disabled value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**I'm also loading data from a REST API to display it on the frontend :**

```
    var detailProject = Restangular.one('projects', $routeParams.projectId);
    detailProject.get().then(function (project) {
        $scope.project = project;

        $scope.saveProject = function () {
            project.put().then(processSuccess, processError);
        };

    });
```

Once I click on save, a saveProject function puts back the data to the API.

Now... How do I link up the states with the Countries?

From what I understood in the documentation, I would need to change the ng-model properties to reflect country and state... like so :

```
<select id="country" ng-model="states" ng-options=""></select>
<select id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-options=""></select>
```

But I'm a bit confused, how can I do that when I want the API data to be loaded in the select boxes?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for hours... I finally figured it out. Posting this for everyone who might encounter the same issue.

I modified my data, splitting countries and states into 2 different files

**Countries:**

```
[
    { "name": "United States" },
    { "name": "Canada" }
    etc...
]
```

**States:**

```
[
    { "name": "Alabama", "country": "United States" },
    { "name": "Alberta", "country": "Canada" }
    etc...
]
```

**Modified HTML**

```
<select data-ng-model="project.country" data-ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in countries" data-ng-change="updateCountry()" class="form-control">
    <option disabled value="">Select country</option>
</select>


<select data-ng-disabled="!project.country" data-ng-model="project.province" data-ng-options="state.name as state.name for state in states | filter:{country: availableStates}" class="form-control">
    <option disabled value="">Select state</option>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.updateCountry = function () {
    $scope.availableStates = $scope.project.country; // filter by country
    $scope.project.province = ''; // reset the province field to empty
};
```

Comment: It's exact the same what **prawn** told you (to use `filter`)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work....

You can filter off the options by `project.country`. I also placed a ng-disabled directive to prevent them from selecting an option in this dropdown if they haven't selected a country first.

```
<select  ng-disabled="!project.country" ng-model="selectedState" 
ng-options="state.value as state.text for state in countriesAndStates.states | filter:{text: project.country}"></select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work <option value="?" selected="selected" label=""></option> is rendered on the FE :(